# Integral over a Markov process

Tags: stochastic-calculus, mathematical-finance

I have the following questions:
Let $Z$ be a continuous one-dimensional Markov process on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and $\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma(Z_s,s \leq t)$. Then show that for all $T > 0$:

for all $t \leq T$ there exists a function $F(t,T,\cdot)$ such that

$$E[e^{-\int_{t}^T R(Z_s) ds} | \mathcal{F}_t] = F(t,T,Z_t),$$

where $R$ is some function. If $Z$ is time-homogeneous then for all $t\leq T$ there exists a function $G$ such that
$$F(t,T,z) = G(T-t,z).$$

So for question (1) I intuitively know that $E[e^{-\int_{t}^T R(Z_s) ds} | \mathcal{F}_t] = E[e^{-\int_{t}^T R(Z_s) ds} | Z_t] $ but how do I prove it?
For question (2) I was thinking about expressing it in terms of $Q_{T-t}f(Z_t)$ where $(Q_{t})_{t \geq 0}$ is the transition semi-group, but since there is an integral expression I have no clue how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question (1): There are many ways to phrase the Markov property. One of the more convenient ones is as follows: if $\Phi$ is a non-negative function measurable with respect to $\mathcal F_{t,\infty} := \sigma\{X_s : s \ge t\}$, then
$$ E[\Phi | \mathcal F_t] = E[\Phi | X_t] \text{ a.s.} $$
Furthermore, by the [Doob–Dynkin lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%E2%80%93Dynkin_lemma), the right-hand side is equal a.s. to a Borel function of $X_t$.

Clearly, in our case $\Phi_{t,T} = \exp(-\int_t^T R(Z_s) ds)$ is $\mathcal F_{t,\infty}$-measurable (thanks to continuity of $Z_s$; I assume that $R$ is nice enough — say: locally bounded from below), so clearly
$$ E[\Phi_{t,T} | \mathcal F_t] = F_{t,T}(X_t) \text{ a.s.} $$
for a Borel function $F_{t,T}$.

The true question is whether we can choose $F_{t,T}$ in such a way that $(t,T,x) \mapsto F_{t,T}(x)$ is jointly measurable. I expect that under reasonable assumptions (say: the function $R$ is bounded from below), this is standard, but tiresome; however, I did not attempt to write a detailed proof.

(What is easy is that $\Phi_{t,T}$ is uniformly bounded and almost surely continuous with respect to $t, T$, and hence, by the dominated convergence theorem, $(t,T) \mapsto \Phi_{t,T}$ is a continuous map into $L^1(\Omega, P)$; in particular, $(t,T) \mapsto F_{t,T}(X_t)$ is a continuous map into $L^1(\Omega, P)$.)

---

The answer to question (2) really depends on your favourite definition of a time-homogeneous Markov process. If we are allowed to use the shift operators $\theta_t$ and expectation $E^x$ for the process started at $x$, then things are pretty clear: we have $\Phi_{t,T} = \Phi_{0,T-t} \circ \theta_t$, and hence
$$ E[\Phi_{t,T} | \mathcal F_t] = E[\Phi_{0,T-t} \circ \theta_t | \mathcal F_t] = G_{T-t}(X_t) , $$
where
$$ G_s(x) = E^x \Phi_{0,s} $$
is a Borel function. Noteworthy, here joint measurability of $(s,x) \mapsto G_s(x)$ presents no difficulties: $s \mapsto \Phi_{0,s}$ is a continuous map into $L^1(\Omega, P)$, and so $s \mapsto G_s(x)$ is continuous for every $x$.

---

I should also add that there is no simple expression for the conditional expectation of the *Feynman–Kac functional* $\Phi_{t,T}$ in terms of the transition semigroup of the process.

Comment: thank you very much for your quick answer. Regarding (1), I have never seen this definition to be honest, the definition I know is actually the other way around:

$$E[f(X_t) | \mathcal{F}_s] = E[f(X_t) | Z_s].$$

where $\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma(X_s ; s \leq t)$

Comment: For (2), your notation for the function $\Phi$ got me thinking about the simple Markov property, and I came up with the following solution:

Let $\mathbb{D}(\mathbb{R})$ be set of cadlag functions $t \mapsto f(t)$ Define
$\Phi_{T-t}:\mathbb{D}(\mathbb{R}) \mapsto [0,\infty)$

by 

$\Phi_{T-t}(f) = e^{-\int_0^{T-t} f(s) ds}.$

 by simple Markov property

$E_{Z_t}[\Phi_{T-t}] = E[\phi((R(Z_{t+s}))_{s \geq 0}) | \mathcal{F}_t] = E[e^{-\int_0^{T-t} R(Z_{s+t}) ds} | \mathcal{F}_t] =  E[e^{-\int_t^{T} R(Z_s) ds} | \mathcal{F}_t],$

thus define  $G(T-t,Z_t) := E_{Z_t}[\Phi_{T-t}].$

Comment: So my solution 2 is equivalent to yours using the shift operator

Comment: Regarding your first comment: this is equivalent. Indeed, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $f(X_t)$, where $t \geqslant s$ and $f$ is a Borel function, is precisely the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F_{s,\infty}$ in my answer.

Comment: In your second comment, you either implicitly use the shift operators (as suggested by the notation $\phi((R(Z_{t+s}))_{s\geqslant 0})$; I guess you meant $\Phi_{T-t}$ rather than $\phi$) or you work with the canonical realisation of the process with $\Omega$ being simply $\mathbb D(\mathbb R)$ (as suggested by $E_{Z_t}[\Phi_{T-t}]$. Both are fine, but mixing them is somewhat inconsistent.

Comment: Sorry yes I meant $\Phi_{T-t}$, but I fail to see how $E[\Phi | \mathcal{F}_t]= E[\Phi|X_t] $. I know that this holds if $X$ is the canonical process since we can use the shift operator which generates the $\sigma$-algebra of the future $\mathcal{F}_{t,\infty}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)},$ but for general Markov processes there is no shift operator. So I guess we just show $E[\Phi | \mathcal{F}_t] = E_{X_t}[\Phi],$ by using the same proof as for the canonical case,i.e by monotone class theorem.

Comment: Further there is also a general simple Markov property given by: Let $X$ be a Markov process, $s \geq 0$ and  $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a measurable function.
Then
$$E[\Phi(t \mapsto X_{s+t}) | \mathcal{F}_s] = E_{X_s}[\Phi].$$ So my question: Can we prove these results by using the related results for the canonical Markov process, or do we just adapt the proves that we used for the canonical Markov process, since the proofs only use the marginal distributions

Comment: Sorry for all the comments but 
I think I get it. Let $\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma(X_s; s \leq t), \hat{\mathcal{F}}_t = \sigma(X_s; s \geq t)$. If $Z\geq 0$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable then exists $f: \mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)} \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ s.t $Z = f(s \mapsto X_{s}; s \leq t)$. If its $\hat{\mathcal{F}}_t$- measurable there exists a $\tilde{f}: \mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)} \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ s.t $Z = \tilde{f}(s) \mapsto X_{s}; s \geq t)$. Now we just use the general simple Markov property which I stated above and all the results including the one for the canonical Process follow.

Comment: You seem to be over-complicating things. Let $\mathcal G$ be the class of events $A$ such that $P[A|\mathcal F_t] = P[A|X_t]$. Then, by the usual statement of the Markov property, $\mathcal G$ contains all events $X_s \in B$ for Borel $B$ and $s \geqslant t$. Furthermore, $\mathcal G$ is a Dynkin system, and hence it contains $\mathcal F_{t,\infty}$.

Comment: Regarding the existence of $\tilde f$ in you last comment: watch out for measurability issues. All functions $\tilde f$ measurable with respect to $\mathbb R^{[0,\infty)}$ (equipped with the usual product $\sigma$-algebra) depend on countably many coordinates, so no chance that such a $\tilde f$ exists with $\tilde f((X_t)) = \Phi_{0,T-t}$ for all measurable functions $(X_t)$. For continuous (or even càdlàg) processes, this might actually work, though.